# Configuring Apache - Web server with WebSphere Base Edition - App server? WebSphere base edition cluster feature?

Tags: apache, websphere, websphere-8

Architecture :-1

End user ->  1 Load balancer -> 2 web servers ( Apache - RHEL 7.5 ) -> 2 App servers ( WebSphere 8.5.5.11 )

1. I know that more than 5 nodes cluster can be configure with WAS ND and heard about Cluster can be configured in WAS Base edition with 5 nodes. Our requirement is that we would like to configure cluster with 2 nodes in WAS base edition,is this possible with WAS Base edition? Is there any license issue on WAS Base edition with 2 node ?  Am I right? kindly clarify cluster feature in WAS Base editon.
2. How to configure Cluster/HA/Active-Active with two nodes in WebSphere application server. If I configure Active/active cluster in WAS App then Load balancer is required infront of the web servers?
3. How to configure web server ( Apache ) with App server ( Websphere )
4. Is it required to configure DMGR when I configure Cluster with two nodes on WebSphere Base edition? Someone told me that DMGR cannot create in WebSphere base editon?

Answer (score 0):

A "cluster" in the Base edition is not a cluster at all to the appserver, it is just a bunch of standalone servers with the same config and applications with a HTTP proxy that load balances between them.

If you use the WAS WebServer Plugin to achieve it, you generate a plugin-cfg.xml on each system then use the pluginMerge tool in the bin/ directory on any appserver to merge them into one.

No dmgr is required when using Base in this way.